# Div disappears in Safari only

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I have a div that is initially `position: relative` but when clicked, it gains `position: fixed` as I want it to then cover the whole screen. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari the div disappears entirely.

If I inspect the element, I can see where it is supposed to be but it is just invisible.

The element in question is `<article class="panel">`, the purple one that says "Organic Chemistry".

https://jsfiddle.net/cupkpyrm/1/

Comment: I am not too sure what are you trying to achieve here, but removing **overflow: auto** from **#content** will fix this, I tried this on Chrome as well.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much